# How to get ad-hoc and RRAS working together in WS2016?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, ad-hoc-network, windows-server-2016

My PC have 2 ports, one is WAN (x.x.x.x), second if is LAN(manually assigned it 192.168.1.1). NAT and RRAS are up and running ok. Internet is reachable from lan PCs. Then i've managed to add up wireless adapter. I assigned it 192.168.1.2. Then stumbled for a bit. First of all, Win10, and EVEN WS2016 lacks appropriate configuration for it!! Okay, I followed guides and installed Wireless Serivices via powershell.
Then created that network from cmd as admin:

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=mynet key=mypass`

And started it:

`netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

It created some third adapter, "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter", which is only visible in device manager when **show hidden devices** is enabled.
Also it created some new wifi connecion, called "Local Area Connection* 12". I can find it in "network and sharing center>adapters" I cant get what for, but okay, i've assigned it 192.168.1.3

Now i'm wishing to add this virtual adapter to RRAS routing snapin, but there is no virtual adapter, neither wifi adapter on the list. So i can connect from notebook to improvised ad hoc network, DHCP assigns it some address 192.168.1.100 for the case, i can ping 192.168.1.3 from there, but.. i cant reach internet from wlan, neither 192.168.1.1.. and it also gives connecting device default gateway address 192.168.1.1. How to solve the puzzle?

PS. i cant install linux here (

PPS. i cant afford router (((

Answer (score 2):

Ah okay after searching i was lucky to finally find an answer - [disable RRAS and enable-reconfigure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/isablog/2012/06/27/newly-added-network-adapter-not-showing-up-in-rras-with-forefront-tmg/) it in the snapin to get everyithing up and running..

seems snapin has its own separate list of adapters, and you need to re-read when adding or removing hardware adapters